# CodedUI exception: UITestControlNotFoundException: Addional Details: TechnologyName: 'MSAA' ControlType: 'MenuItem' Name: 'All'

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Test method CodedUITestProject6.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException:
>   The playback failed to find the control with the given search
>   properties. Additional Details:  TechnologyName:  'MSAA' ControlType: 
>   'MenuItem' Name:  'All'

I am using CodedUI to automate my application, and getting above exception during playing the automated test while selecting menuitem from drop down menu.

Comment: more info is needed - what search properties are u using? do you always get the exception or sometimes you manage to find the control?

Answer (score 0):

add some wait because when you expand menu list takes some time to be visible on screen.To me this seems to be your problem